# Find $U \in H^1(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ such that $\nabla E(u-\bar u)\nabla U \geq 0?$ (PDE harmonic extension)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain. Given $u \in H^{\frac 12}(\Omega)$ with mean value $\bar u = 0$, let $Eu = v \in H^1(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ solve
$$\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega \nabla v\nabla \varphi = 0$$
$$v(x,0) = u$$
$$\partial_\nu v|_{\partial\Omega \times [0,\infty)} = 0$$
where $\nabla$ is the gradient in both $x$ and $y$ variables and $\nu$ is the unit normal.

We have in fact that $v(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda^{\frac 12}_j y}(u, \varphi_j)\varphi_j(x)$ where $(\lambda_j, \varphi_j)$ are eigenelements of the Neumann Laplacian on $\Omega$.

---

Now let $u \in H^{\frac 12}(\Omega)$ with $\bar u \neq 0$. Is it possible to find an element $U \in H^1(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ such that $U(x,0) = u$ (in the sense of trace) and 
$$\nabla E(u-\bar u)\nabla U \geq 0$$
pointwise a.e. with $\lVert U \rVert_{L^2(\Omega \times (0,\infty))} \leq C\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$?

---

The problem is that I don't know the sign of $\bar u$... and since $\bar u$ is a constant (independent of space) it has infinite $L^2(\Omega \times (0,\infty))$ norm.